# lose type then importing from self module

Tags: typescript

I use axios. then import it i get type variable with autocomplete:

[image]

How its work internal axios.ts:

[image]

Now i try create wrapper http.ts that also return type:

[image]

but i lose type and autocomplete then import module:

[image]

What is difference? What is problem?

Comment: What does your IDE show when you try to _use_ your `http` imported module? Sometimes VSCode shows different IntelliSense on the import statement compared to actual code.

Comment: dont show methods , only "shared" for all cases